# Question on multivariate probability distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm given the density function $$f(y_1, y_2) = \begin{cases}6(1-y_2), & 0\le y_1\le y_2 \le 1,\\
0, & \text{elswhere.} \end{cases} $$ and asked to find $P(Y_1 \le 3/4, Y_2 \ge 1/2)$ which the solution manual says is  $$P(Y_1 \le 3/4, Y_2 \ge 1/2)=\int_{1/2}^{1}\int_{1/2}^{1}6(1-y_2)dy_1dy_2 + \int_{1/2}^{3/4}\int_{y_1}^{1}6(1-y_2)dy_2dy_1 = \frac{31}{64}$$

could someone explain to me why this is the case?  How did they determine to split up the integrals like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first pair of limits is incorrect.

The shaded region is the portion over which the density function is positive with the darker region the region of integration.

[image: region of integration]

So it should be

$$ \int_0^{1/2}\int_{1/2}^1f(y_1,y_2)\,dy_2dy_1+\int_{1/2}^{3/4}\int_{y_1}^1f(y_1,y_2)\,dy_2dy_1 $$

**ADDENDUM:**
You should double-check my results but I got $\dfrac{3}{4}+\dfrac{7}{64}=\dfrac{55}{64}$

**OOPS!** Double-checked it myself, it is $\dfrac{3}{8}+\dfrac{7}{64}=\dfrac{31}{64}$ so I suspect that your answer book just accidentally messed up the first two limits of integration since the they got the numerical answer correct.

Comment: I noticed that when I wrote up my answer I had accidentally reversed the order of integration. That has been corrected.

Comment: I also corrected an error. So now my final answer agrees with your answer book's final answer.